# Where is the center tile for a 2 by 2 checkerboard?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm given the following theorem to prove:

> For all $n\ge0$, there exists a way to tile a $2^n×2^n$ courtyard with a center tile missing (to tile a statue).

However, for a 2 by 2 checkerboard, I'm not sure exactly where the center tile is located. Each tile is L-shaped.

Comment: What are we tiling it with?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: I don't think that clarified very much.  What is the basic unit of tiling?  For instance, if the basic unit is just a $1 \times 1$ square, then of course the answer is yes.  If the basic unit is just a $1 \times 2$ domino, the answer is just as obviously no.  I'm going to guess that it is the simple L-triomino, because that's a somewhat interesting question, but you should make it clearer.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you are tiling it with.  I would guess it is L trominoes, in which case you can tile $2n \times 2n$ with any square missing.  Note there is not a center tile for $4 \times 4$ or any other even side, eitherj.

Comment: @RossMillikan: You have anticipated me!

Comment: Brian and Ross, yep, these are L trominoes.

Comment: most likely the OP is referring to the classic triomino tiling puzzle for a $2^n *2^n$ board

Answer (score 2):

Notice the theorem says "a center tile", not "the center tile". That seems designed to indicate that any one of the four most-central tiles can be called the center; because of symmetry, it doesn't matter which one is so designated.

But note that the theorem as stated is incorrect! Take $n=3$: a $6\times 6$ courtyard with a single tile removed cannot be tiled by L-shaped trominoes, since every L covers exactly 3 squares.

If $2n$ is replaced by $2^n$, then the theorem becomes a classic induction problem; perhaps that's what's intended?

Comment: Thank you, yes its supposed to be 2^n. This explains everything correctly.